# Issue with connecting to MongoDB docker container with another container

Tags: python, django, mongodb, docker

Having an issue with connecting to a docker container to another container.  I'm able to connect to it locally outside the container but from within the container doesn't work. This is the stack trace

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 5f9cf7b6d9d395e79548d42a, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]>
```

My docker-compose.yml file is pretty straight forward and simple. Nothing unique

```
  mongod:
    restart: always
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: mongod

  app:
    build: ./app
    container_name: django-gunicorn
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./app/django.env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command:
      "gunicorn --workers=2 --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 webapp.wsgi:application"
```

I've binded the port to 0.0.0.0 in the mongod.conf. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to connect to `localhost`, but the hostname of mongodb container will be the service name given in `docker-compose.yml` file

update the connection params to use

```
host="mongod",# name of service in compose file
```